# Getting "Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib" error

Tags: xcode, git-submodules

The problem occurred when I adding Nimble as a git submodule. I've fired an [issue](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/issues/399) on [Quick/Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble), but the problem appears to be not likely a Nimble issue, it maybe rather an Xcode issue, thus I'm asking here.

I set up a simple project according to Nimble installation guid and it's on [github](https://github.com/Nandiin/NimbleIssue) now. Basically I created an `xcworkspace` and an `xcodeproj` (added to the workspace). Nimble is added as git submodule and subproject to the workspace. Then I added Nimble.framework to my test targets Build Phases and wrote some simple test code to see if Nimble was running.

And when I run the test, Xcode gave this error message:

```
2017-02-20 23:41:29.482 xctest[52165:616190] The bundle “MainProjTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2017-02-20 23:41:29.483 xctest[52165:616190] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/nandiin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NimbleIssue-fkhppktoktwpjodtarmzrjobszwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MainProjTests.xctest/MainProjTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nandiin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NimbleIssue-fkhppktoktwpjodtarmzrjobszwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nimble.framework/Nimble
  Reason: image not found)
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

I've tried some solution I found for similar problems and they didn't work:

- setting `Embed Asset Packs In Product Bundle` to `YES` (tried for both main target and test target)
- setting `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` (tried for both main target and test target)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the run path for the dynamic library:

```
libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
```

If this is not included in the app bundle after building your app you'll want to add it by including it in the `Copy Files Build Phase`. Another possible problem could be that it's run path is not correctly set ( which you'll need to set if not already ), or fix the `rpath` with `install_name_tool`.

↳ [Run-Path Dependent Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html)